# Paypal PDT is not sent for recurring payments

Tags: paypal, subscription, eclipse-pdt, recurring

I am testing PDT functionality on Paypal's Sandbox. As far as I understand PDT should be send when Payment Transfer occurs. So I expect to receive PDT with every recurring payment. 
However Paypal calls my PDT returning link only the first time but when recurring payment happens then Payment Data Transfer returning link is not called despite fact that payment occurred. I think probably IPN is sent, but I don't want to use both since PDT is enough for me.

Am I missing something? How payment for subscription when signing up is not considered payment when recurring?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Well, I ened up using hybrid solution using both PDT and IPN. Since IPN may have some delays (and it has a big ones as I experienced) and I needed instant check if subscription is valid to provide service to  users of my application so I used PDT for that validation and PDT link is called by Paypal without delay. Later when recurring payment occurs IPN link is called and I do validate recurring payment (PDT is not called). It works for me since i need provide service instantly after Paypal order but internally we give extra day for subscriptions so delays with recurring IPN calls is OK.

Comment: I might end up doing this hybrid myself, thanks for your response. I was thinking about the possibility of having the success url of the IPN activate the subscription temporarily and have the real IPN define it later, but there might be a security issue where some cust can manually call the success url after login.

Comment: Well, regarding manual call of success url of IPN there is some security procedure against manual calls. When your your IPN url is called first time you validate it and  just call back special Paypal link with the same received info. Yes this you have to implement but Paypal has examples for that. Only then you receive back response with transaction information. So if someone call your IPN url manually it will not work if you implement validation correctly. However my problem was that I was selling subscription  and IPN url was sometime called 6 or 7 hours after actual subscription.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I was talking about the URLs for "cancel" and "return" you set in paypal so if a transaction is completed, paypal will redirect to the "return" url. Otherwise to the "cancel" url. So activate temporarily on the "return" url and then show the app. Handle the actual "IPN" when you receive it. This approach would have the security trouble.